# Using String variable to create android imageview

Tags: java, android, imageview

i want to do like let user to add a new item which user can enter item name, item description, item price and so on. let say the name variable stored candy and i have a candy image in my drawable can i do like R.drawable.name to refer to R.drawable.candy?? Anyone help pls

```
public class item {
    String name;
    String desc;
    double price;
    int itemimage;

    public item(String name, String desc, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.price = price;

        itemimage = R.drawable.name;//my question is here
        //i want to have auto define the image of the item for later use
        // so i can do like set imageview of this item
        //i will have the image have same name with item name
        // for example my item name is candy
        //then i will have a image at the android drawable named candy
        //so in android to define this image is R.drawable.candy
        // can i do like R.drawable.name  <-- variable store with value candy
        // is it same with R.drawable.candy
    }
}//end class item

//another class
public class main {
    Arraylist<item> itemdatabase = new Arraylist<item>();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter item name:");
    String itemname = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter item desc:");
    String itemdesc = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter item price:");
    double itemprice = input.nextDouble();

    itemdatabase.add(new

    item(itemname, itemdesc, itemprice);
}
```

Comment: But you have a lot of statements outside of methods. Didn't the compiler complain about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Resources.getIdentifier()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). For `R.drawable.candy`, you'd use it like this:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("candy", "drawable", getPackageName());
// now `id` == R.drawable.candy
```

This code assumes you're running inside an `Activity`. If not, you'll need access to a `Context` instance so that you can call `Context.getResources()` and `Context.getPackageName()`. That might look like this:

```
int id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("candy", "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is No, You can not do like R.drawable.name